# Sending emails without mailables in Laravel works except for the cc/bcc recipients

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I need to send some test emails from Laravel and want to do it, without Mail classes, etc. I usually use the `Mail::send()` function for this and it works fine.  However, I've just realized that *cc/bcc* recipients don't seem to work when using this form.

In case useful to know, I'm using sendmail.

```
$result=Mail::send('site.emails.empty-template', ['msg'=>"Hi this is a test msg"], function ($message) {
    $message->from('noreply@me.com');
    $message->subject("A test email");
    $message->to("to@test.com");
    $message->cc("cc@test.com");
    $message->bcc(["bcc1@test.com","bcc2@test.com]);
});
```

Comment: ***syntax error in your code. Near the `bcc` line.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mail::send` method, and by using this, you can customize your `subject` and `body`.

```
$options = [
    'cc' => 'cc@test.com',
    'bcc' => ['bcc1@test.com', 'bcc2@test.com'],
];

Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($email, $options) {
    $message->to($email)
            ->cc($options['cc'])
            ->bcc($options['bcc'])
            ->subject('A test emai')
            ->setBody('This is the email content.', 'text/html');
});
```

**OR**

you may use this one

**Create a new mailable class**

```
 php artisan make:mail MyMail
```

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.my-email')
                    ->cc(['cc@test.com']);
    }
}
```

**Use class to send the email**

```
 Mail::to($email)->send(new MyMail());
```

Comment: Using your 1st example I get: 

Symfony\Component\Mime\Message::setBody(): Argument #1 ($body) must be of type ?Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart, string
- Is there maybe something wrong with my setup, you and another user suggested examples that both gave this error so I am concluding that maybe my setup has an issue?

Comment: `$options = [
    'cc' => 'cc@test.com',
    'bcc' => ['bcc1@test.com', 'bcc2@test.com'],
];

Mail::send('site.emails.empty-template', [], function ($message) use ($email, $options) {
    $message->to($email)
            ->cc($options['cc'])
            ->bcc($options['bcc'])
            ->subject('A test email')
            ->setBody('This is the email content.', 'text/html');
});`
try this, I think `The Mail::send() method expects a view or an array with data` may this one will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this:

```
Mail::to($email)
    ->cc(['foo@domain.com','bar@doamin.com'])
    ->send('something');
```

Comment: I get this:  Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::send(): Argument #1 ($mailable) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable, string given

Comment: @AdamJones Check the return type of your function and change it.

Comment: @anayarojo I am following the example given in this answer.    It's the "something" from the example code that is the issue here, causing the Argument #1 error.

Answer (score 0):

In bcc there's an " closing issue:

```
$result=Mail::send('site.emails.empty-template', ['msg'=>"Hi this is a test msg"], function ($message) {
    $message->from('noreply@me.com');
    $message->subject("A test email");
    $message->to("to@test.com");
    $message->cc("cc@test.com");
    
    // $message->bcc(["bcc1@test.com","bcc2@test.com]);
    $message->bcc(["bcc1@test.com","bcc2@test.com"]);
});
```

> Note: For multiple emails you've to pass array

You can visit these links as a reference:

[Send e-mail without implementing a Mailable class #41632](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/41632)

[Laravel send email without Mailable](https://insideofcode.com/blog/laravel-send-email-without-mailable/)

You can also try like this:

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to("to@test.com")
    ->subject("A test email")
    ->cc("cc@test.com")
    ->bcc(["bcc1@test.com","bcc2@test.com"])
    // here comes what you want
    ->setBody('Hi Adam'); // assuming text/plain
    // or:
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi Adam</h1>', 'text/html'); // for HTML rich messages
});
```

Comment: Thanks but trying the 2nd example I just get: 

Symfony\Component\Mime\Message::setBody(): Argument #1 ($body) must be of type ?Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart, string given

-  Is there maybe something wrong with my setup, you and another user suggested examples that both gave this error so I am concluding that maybe my setup has an issue?

Comment: @AdamJones if you're using Laravel 9 then for html you've to replace `->setBody('<h1>Hi Adam</h1>', 'text/html');` with `->html('<h1>HTML</h1>')->text('Plain Text');`

Comment: @AdamJones for Laravel 8  `->setBody('<h1>HTML</h1>', 'text/html')->addPart('Plain Text', 'text/plain');`