# Laravel isn't sending to my CC's and BCC contacts when standard PHP mail() code does

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I raised a [question a week or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75880487/sending-emails-without-mailables-in-laravel-works-except-for-the-cc-bcc-recipien) back about the syntax for sending emails using the standard Laravel mail conventions, specifically including cc/bcc recipients.

My assumption was that my code was incorrect and for this reason whenever I tried to email with cc/bcc recipients it didn't work.  When I say it didn't work, I mean that "to" recipients received the email, but nobody specified as a "cc" / "bcc" recipient did.

However, having tried all the code samples given in that post and having undertaken further testing it seems that this assumption was incorrect.

By more testing, I mean that I've now made simple test pages of PHP that use the default PHP mail() function.  Using these, the cc/bcc recipients DO work.

So this suggests something in the Laravel setup must be at fault.  However it isn't something fundamental such as my mail config because sending to normal recipients that are not cc/bcc works reliability with no issue.

I've also varied my test cc/bcc recipients quite a lot and the mails never arrive for any of them.  So this isn't specific to a certain email platform or receiving server that is rejecting them.

So what could be wrong here?  Any ideas?

What options do I have to enable verbose logging to the  mail mechanisms in Laravel (v9) ?

Example code for sending to cc/bcc recipients:

```
$options = [
    'cc' => 'cc@test.com',
    'bcc' => ['bcc1@test.com', 'bcc2@test.com'],
];

Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($email, $options) {
    $message->to($email)
            ->cc($options['cc'])
            ->bcc($options['bcc'])
            ->subject('A test emai')
            ->html('This is the email content.', 'text/html');
});
```

Comment: check your mailservice logs if the mail is going out. you also should get a response from the other mail server if it is rejected

Comment: show your code in the current question

Comment: now added @lagbox

Comment: The obvious issue is that `options` is missing it's `$`, i.e. `options = [...]` vs `$options = [...]`, but I also assume that is simply a typo when you asked this question? Have you done `dd($options['cc'], $options['bcc'])` to see if they're correct? Beyond that, your code looks ok to me.

Comment: @AdamJones
One thing that comes to my mind that may cause it is this line: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1c2eef82924ff5f9ae14b0fad9f70f5f922a0d17/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L408. Do you have global "to" address configured in your config?

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis yes that was my bad, fixed my demo code.

Comment: @Amade you may be on to something! Where is this global "to" meant to be configured?

Comment: Obvious question, if you hardode emails in TO,CC,BCC are they delivered?

Comment: @AdamJones In your config/mail.php file. Previous docs version also mentioned other ways to configure that, see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#using-a-global-to-address.

Comment: @AdamJones Just put dd('foo') on top of this line to debug it:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1c2eef82924ff5f9ae14b0fad9f70f5f922a0d17/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L294
It's the only this method is used in Laravel's codebase (at least in v10).

Comment: @Amade thanks for the help but this isn't the issue. I don't have that global variable configured and sadly adding a dd() in the framework mail file doesn't break code execution.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator hardcode how exactly ?

Comment: You don't explicitly mention it but I am assuming you have made sure that an address that successfully receives a msg as a `to` does *not* receive a msg when they are instead a `cc` or `bcc`, and vice-versa, to rule out the simple flagged-as-spam trivial solution?  Otherwise, have you tried using [the documented syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#sending-mail) for sending mail, with Mailables?

Comment: how much is the execution time difference for the laravel code where only `to` receives mail vs php mail function where 'everyone' receives ?

Answer (score 0):

From version **9.x** of Laravel, the previously used **SwiftMailer** became outdated, and its support has been discontinued. Instead, **Symfony Mailer** has been introduced. (For more information, see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer)

The syntax of Symfony Mailer is slightly different, so source codes related to Message::class before 2022 may not be 100% reliable.

**NOW**

If you are using **Laravel 9.x or higher**, use the following code:

```php
$options = [
    'cc' => 'cc@test.com',
    'bcc' => ['bcc1@test.com', 'bcc2@test.com'],
];

Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($email, $options) {
    $message
            ->to($email)
            ->cc($options['cc'])
            ->bcc($options['bcc'])
            ->subject('A test emai')
            ->html('This is the email content.');
});
```

**OUTDATED (from 9.x)**

If you are using **Laravel 8.x or lower**, you should always try to pass an array to the `cc` and `bcc` functions:

```php
$options = [
    'cc' => ['cc@test.com'],
    'bcc' => ['bcc1@test.com', 'bcc2@test.com'],
];

Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($email, $options) {
    $message
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setCc($options['cc'])
            ->setBcc($options['bcc'])
            ->setSubject('A test emai')
            ->setBody('This is the email content.', 'text/html');
});
```

Comment: I'm using V9 and my own sample code is basically the same as yours, so I don't believe this is the issue.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however, the `setBody()` function is deprecated. Instead, the `html()` and/or `text()` functions can be used in Laravel 9 or higher versions.

Comment: Before submitting the function I wrote in my answer, I tested it and it worked. I only tested it with different email addresses! The recipient, the email address passed to cc, and the array of email addresses passed to bcc all received the email. If it still doesn't work, then the problem is not with this function, but without further information, we don't know more about your problem.

Comment: it is the same using setBody() or html().   So it seems to be elsewhere, but that is exactly what my original question is, where could it be ?  I am not doing anything unstandard/bespoke with the email setup of this Laravel install.

Comment: I don't really understand. When using the setBody function in Laravel 9, you should get an error message that the setBody function cannot be found, and the code should work perfectly with the html function. If it also sends the email to you with the setBody function, it's very suspicious.

Comment: I tested it again. If you run it with "setBody", you should get the following error message! `Symfony\Component\Mime\Message::setBody(): Argument #1 ($body) must be of type ?Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart, string given`

Comment: In my opinion, your problem may stem from here. If I had to guess, it's not the code you're editing that ultimately sends the emails. If you comment out the code I pasted in my example and your code still sends the emails, then the problem is probably where you send them from. It's likely that cc or bcc is not declared there.

Comment: Sorry @rozsazoltan this was a red herring, I also get that error now, so it seems my example wasn't quite correct. I've updated it.

Comment: Since the code runs without errors, it seems to me that the problem is not to be found here onwards. The code is correct. It might be worth checking the email client as well. If you run the same code in a different environment, does it also produce a lack of cc and bcc? **When you send the email, is there any error in the log of your mail server (e.g. cpanel) that would indicate that the message could not be delivered?**